# revtex4-1 changes the way authors are written with respect to revtex4

Tags: revtex, author

I was using `revtex4` and the authors were written in the most natural way, that is you first write all the authors' names and then you list the affiliations with the proper numbering.

Then, when I moved to `revtex4-1` the authors ended up being grouped together according to the shared affiliation, and otherwise the scheme would be first author's name, then their affiliation, then new author's name etc etc, which is not what I want.

How can I have the standard format "all the authors' names, then all the affiliations" with `revtex4-1`?

This is what I was doing

```
\documentclass[aps,pre,onecolumn,noshowpacs,superscriptaddress,groupedaddress,preprintnumbers,nofootinbib,showpacs,floatfix,12pt]{revtex4-1}

%...
%...


\author{Donald}
 \thanks{Equal contributions}
\affiliation{university of london}
\author{Peter}
\thanks{Equal contributions}
\affiliation{university of madrid}
\affiliation{another university of madrid}
```

and so far the output is

```
Donald 
university of london
Peter
university of madrid
another university of madrid
```

whereas of course what I want is

```
Donald 1 , Peter 2,3 
1 university of london
2 university of madrid
3 another university of madrid
```

EDIT

**Solution**

My mistake was to include `groupedaddress`. By removing it the problem is solved.

Comment: revtex4-1 is obsolete (and so not necessarly installed in a standard tex system), the current version is revtex4-2

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you. Unfortunately with revtex4-2 I have the same problem.

Comment: Quite possible. But your chance to get help are better if your example use a current version.